# how to clone linked repositories

Tags: git, github

I tried to clone the following repository:

```
# git clone https://github.com/bgruening/docker-galaxy-stable.git
```

However, *docker-galaxy-stable/galaxy/roles/galaxyprojectdotorg.galaxyextras/* does not show any linked files from the other repository.

How is it possible to clone also the linked files and folders?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to fetch that submodule. First initalize submodule `git submodule init`, then `git submodule update`. You could also pass `--recursive` option to clone so it fetches also submodules. Read more about git submodules here https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules